# Do we modify our build gradle when we create a new package?

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle

I'm a beginner in android studio, so i downloaded this code and wanted to add authentification on it, for that i created a new package "com.example.authapp".
[image]

So when i tried to connect to firebase i get the following error :

```
Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync.
```

so i wondred shoul i add something in my gradles?

The content of my gradles:
1/build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    google()
    maven {
        url 'https://alphacephei.com/maven/'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.vosk.demo"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1"
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64', 'x86'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.8.0@aar'
    implementation group: 'com.alphacephei', name: 'vosk-android', version: '0.3.23'
    implementation project(':models')
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
}
```

2/build.gradle(models)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig = false
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets.srcDirs += "$buildDir/generated/assets"
        }
    }
}

tasks.register('genUUID') {
    def uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    def odir = file("$buildDir/generated/assets/model-en-us")
    def ofile = file("$odir/uuid")
    doLast {
        mkdir odir
        ofile.text = uuid
    }
}

preBuild.dependsOn(genUUID)
```

3/build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Please help me, and what should i do to be able to connect to firebase?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to build is called a multi-module app since you added a different package. I don't that was your intention since you mentioned you're a beginner.

So here are the steps to have your implementation

1. Create an **Activity** names LoginActivity inside com.vosk.demo and apply your firebase functionality there
2. Set your Loginactivity as the **Launcher Activity**
3. On successful authentication pass an **Intent** to get to the next activity